# EKS - mount a secret manager with file name definition

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am using AWS EKS cluster and made a configuration to load secrets manager to my pod:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-secrets-store-inline10
spec:
  serviceAccountName: test-sm-service-account
  namespace: test-sm
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: mysecret2
      mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
      readOnly: true

  volumes:
    - name: mysecret2
      csi:
        driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
        readOnly: true
        volumeAttributes:
          secretProviderClass: "aws-secrets"
```

That mounts my secret manager into the folder "/mnt/secrets-store". But what I need to do is to specify a proper name for it, so it should be like "/mnt/secrets-store/**myname.txt**".

How can I properly do that? I was not able to find any proper configuration. I need this file to be properly named before my application starts.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1- name your CSI volume `myname.txt` and mount it with that name inside your pod, as a result when you exec inside your pod it will be found with path `/mnt/secrets-store/myname.txt`

2- use `subpath` :

```
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mnt/secrets-store/myname.txt
      name: mysecret2
      subPath: myname.txt
```

Note that if using subPath volume mount, the secret updates are not propagated on rotation. This is a known limitation (see details [here](https://secrets-store-csi-driver.sigs.k8s.io/known-limitations#secrets-not-rotated-when-using-subpath-volume-mount)).

The only way to get the latest content is to restart the pod or not use `subPath` volume mount.